# Powershell script awaits for user input in windows8.1 jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, code-signing

I am trying to run a powershell script (.\BuildMDILAPPX.ps1) from jenkins in windows 8.1 to sign an .appx file , When I run it from the  powershell command prompt
as administrator it get executes successfully and at last it ask me should it keep the input files or not (through a dialog box) and when click (either yes or no) it will open the folder containing the output .

When I try the same script through Jenkins its gets stuck at where it asks for the input from me through.

How can I pass the value at the time of execution of the powershell command ( so that it will complete the execution by saving the signed file )or is there any other work around. please help

Comment: __"How can I pass the value at the time of execution of the powershell command"__ - That depends on the script. If you didn't write it, see if there is a help command and look for a parameter that allows you to specify that option. If you did write it, include such a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using **"-silent yes"** parameter suppressed the dialog for me.